# Rspec 'it { should have_db_column(:x).of_type(:y) }' not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

My `attendance_rspec.rb` file contains:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Attendance, type: :model do
    it { should have_db_column(:date).of_type(:date) }
end
```

When I run it from the terminal using `rspec spec/models/attendance_spec.rb`

It shows the error:

```
Failures:

  1) Attendance 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_db_column(:date).of_type(:date) }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `of_type' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x000055e5c65dd3e0>
     # ./spec/models/attendance_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

I already have `FactoryBot` configured along with `database_cleaner` and `capybara` gems. What gem am I missing or any config missing in `rails_helper.rb`?

I followed [this link](https://medium.com/@amliving/my-rails-rspec-set-up-6451269847f9) for setting up Rspec

Comment: Strange, it looks like you're using the correct syntax https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/have_db_column_matcher.rb. Can you check your gem versions?

Comment: `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5' 
gem 'factory_bot_rails' 
gem 'database_cleaner' 
gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0' `

Comment: And the shoulda matchers gem?

Comment: I listed all the gems I installed for rspec..are there more I need?

Comment: This one https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Comment: Yep, that worked for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [NickM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952740/nick-m) pointed out, the [`have_db_column` matcher](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/have_db_column_matcher.rb) is provided by the [`shoulda-matchers`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem. Add it to your Gemfile and [follow the integration steps](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#rails-apps) to use `have_db_column`.

Comment: I think he does have the gem as he's getting the error on .of_type rather than on `should` or `have_db_column`. I'm thinking it's a different version than the one that supports .of_type

Comment: Installed the gem and configured it in `rails_helper.rb` using https://teamtreehouse.com/community/nomethoderror-undefined-method. Working perfectly now!

Comment: @NickM I think that (because of the [`RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has`](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.2/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers/BuiltIn/Has.html) in the traceback) a class from RSpec's private API was instantiated, which doesn't have the `of_type` method. `shoulda_matchers` provides a more specific method to override this behaviour.

Comment: @abdulwasey20 Consider marking the answer as "accepted" if it resolved your problem. Thanks!